# Pandas: Run external library function to create new column efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parsing, processing-efficiency

```
def conv_name(x):
    try:
        #library to convert strings to name dict
        return pp.tag(str(x))[0]
    except:
        return np.nan

dfn = df.name.to_frame()
dfn['conv'] = dfn.name.apply(lambda x: conv_name(x))
dfn['given_name'] = dfn.conv.apply(pd.Series).GivenName
dfn['sunname'] = dfn.conv.apply(pd.Series).Surname
```

Result

[image]

- I have a Pandas Series (df.name) of names.
- I want to parse them using an external library (probablepeople).
- The library returns an exception on some rows so I have put in into the function "conv_name"
- I run the function using df.apply() to create a new column with the results
- I then parse the results into two further column for first and last names

I feel like there must be a way to create the firstname and surname columns without creating dfn.conv but if I do something like ...

```
dfn['given_name'] = dfn.name.apply(lambda x: conv_name(x)['GivenName'])
```

I get a KeyError.

So my specific questions is, how can I create the first and surname columns without creating the conv column?

Comment: Just FYI, `lambda x: conv_name(x)` is the same as simply `conv_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make `conv_name` more efficient by simply returning two values:

```
def conv_name(x):
    try:
        names = pp.tag(str(x))[0]
        return names['GivenName'], names['Surname']
    except:
        return np.nan, np.nan
```

Then, generate both columns at once using `result_type='expand'`:

```
dfn = df.name.to_frame()
names = dfn.name.apply(conv_name, axis=1, result_type='expand')
dfn['given_name'] = names[0]
dfn['surname'] = names[1]
```

The intermediate result `names` will look something like this:

```
          0          1
0       Bob      Smith
1     Bjorn    Janssen
2  Xiaofeng      Cheng
```